# Calculate the Euler-Poincaré characteristic of followin surfaces.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

Calculate the Euler-Poincaré characteristic of:

1. An ellipsoid.
2. The surfase $S=\left\{ \left(x,y,z\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}:x^{2}+y^{10}+z^{6}=1\right\} $.

**Note:** Not how to do this problem, I not really have clear concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the demonstrations, remember a proposition:

> **Proposition $\bigstar$:** Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ an compact connected surface; then one of the values $2,0,-2,\ldots,-2n,\ldots$
>    is assumed by the Euler-Poincaré characteristic  $\mathcal{X}\left(S\right)$.
>   Furthermore, if $S'\subset\mathbb{R}^{3}$ is other compact surface
>   and $\mathcal{X}\left(S\right)=\mathcal{X}\left(S'\right)$, then
>   $S$ is homemorphic to $S'$.

With this in mind we have the following:

1. The procedure is to find a homeomorphism $\varphi$
   between the unit sphere $S^{1}$ and the ellipsoid which we denote as $\mathcal{E}$, where $\mathcal{E}=\left\{ \left(x,y,s\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{3};\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{z^{2}}{c^{2}}=1\right\} $ and where $a,$ $b$ y $c$ are constant nonzero, this idea is expressed graphically in the following figure:

   > [image] $\underrightarrow{\qquad\qquad}{\varphi}$ [image]

   This homeomorphims is:
   $$
   \begin{array}{cccl}
   \varphi: & S^{1} & \rightarrow & \mathcal{E}\\
    & \left(x,y,z\right) & \mapsto & \left(ax,by,cz\right).
   \end{array}
   $$
   This homeomorphims is well-defined because $\varphi\left(x,y,z\right)\in S$
   due to $\frac{\left(ax\right)^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{\left(by\right)^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{\left(cz\right)^{2}}{c^{2}}=x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1$. 
   Additionally, it is clearly injective, we see that it is surjective, indeed, given $\left(\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{z}\right)\in S$ consider the point $\left(\frac{\overline{x}}{a},\frac{\overline{y}}{b},\frac{\overline{z}}{c}\right)$ which satisfies $\varphi\left(\frac{\overline{x}}{a},\frac{\overline{y}}{b},\frac{\overline{z}}{c}\right)=\left(\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{z}\right)$, note that $\left(\frac{\overline{x}}{a}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\overline{y}}{b}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{\overline{z}}{c}\right)^{2}=\frac{\overline{x}^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{\overline{y}^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{\overline{z}^{2}}{c^{2}}=1$, then $\left(\frac{\overline{x}}{a},\frac{\overline{y}}{b},\frac{\overline{z}}{c}\right)\in S^{1}$, so that, $\varphi$ is surjective. The continuity of $\varphi$ is inferred because the components functions are continuous functions. 
   Therefore, $\mathcal{E}$, is homeomorphic to the unit sphere, then $\mathcal{E}$ is a connected compact surface, but by **Proposition $\bigstar$** we have that one of the values $2,0,-2,\ldots,-2n,\ldots$ is assumed by the Euler-Poincare characteristic $\mathcal{X}\left(\mathcal{E}\right)$, but if $\mathcal{X}\left(\mathcal{E}\right)$ assume a different value to $2$ then $\mathcal{E}$ would be homeomorphic to a type of torus, which it means that the unit sphere is homeomorphic to a type of torus, which may not be possible because it contradicts the fact that be simply connected is a topological invariant, so that we have $\mathcal{X}\left(\mathcal{E}\right)=2$.
2. The procedure is to find a homeomorphism $\varphi$
   between the unit sphere $S^{1}$ and $S$, this idea is expressed graphically in the following figure:

   > [image] $\underrightarrow{\qquad\qquad}{\varphi}$ [image]

   This homeomorphims is:
   $$
   \begin{array}{cccl}
   \varphi: & S^{1} & \rightarrow & S\\
    & \left(x,y,z\right) & \mapsto & \left(x,y^{\frac{1}{5}},z^{\frac{1}{3}}\right).
   \end{array}
   $$
   This homeomorphims is well-defined because  $\varphi\left(x,y,z\right)\in S$ due to  $x^{2}+\left(y^{\frac{1}{5}}\right)^{10}+\left(z^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^{6}=x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1$.
   Additionally, it is clearly injective, we see that it is surjective, indeed, given  $\left(\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{z}\right)\in S$ consider the point $\left(\overline{x},\overline{y}^{5},\overline{z}^{3}\right)$
   which satisfies $\varphi\left(\overline{x},\overline{y}^{5},\overline{z}^{3}\right)=\left(\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{z}\right)$, note that $\overline{x}^{2}+\left(\overline{y}^{5}\right)^{2}+\left(\overline{z}^{3}\right)^{2}=\overline{x}^{2}+\overline{y}^{10}+\overline{z}^{6}=1$,
   then $\left(\overline{x},\overline{y}^{5},\overline{z}^{3}\right)\in S^{1}$, so that, $\varphi$ is surjective. The continuity of $\varphi$ is inferred because the components functions are continuous functions. 
   Therefore, $S$ is homeomorphic to the unit sphere, then  $S$ is a connected compact surface, but by **Proposition $\bigstar$** we have that one of the values $2,0,-2,\ldots,-2n,\ldots$ is assumed by the Euler-Poincare characteristic  $\mathcal{X}\left(S\right)$, but if $\mathcal{X}\left(S\right)$ assume a different value to $2$ then  $S$ would be homeomorphic to a type of torus, which it means that the unit sphere is homeomorphic to a type of torus, which may not be possible because it contradicts the fact that be simply connected is a topological invariant, so that we have $\mathcal{X}\left(S\right)=2$.

Comment: You might want to change "convex" to "connected" in the first line of Proposition $\bigstar$.

Comment: You're right, it was a typographical error.